# Process list of commands on remote machine with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will take a list of commands and then run them on a remote machine, I have the following code:

```
foreach($command in $commands)
{
  Invoke-Command -computer "BNEBAK" -scriptblock{"$command"}
}
```

Which does not throw any error but also does not actually run the command (e.g stop-service servicename). $commands is read in from a text file passed as an argument when the script is called, I know the rest of this script works because I have been using it to do local commands with Invoke-Expression for some time.

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Ok I found the problem on this one, it has to do with variable scope the correct way to work around this is to construct a scriptblock separately and then pass it to the Invoke-Command cmdlet like so:

for($command in $commands)
{
$scriptblock = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock($command)
Invoke-Command -computer $computer -scriptblock $scriptblock
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code would be

```
$commands = @(get-content com.txt)
for($command in $commands) { 
  $scriptblock = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock($command) 
  Invoke-Command -computer $computer -scriptblock $scriptblock 
}
```

Comment: The reason for this is that a {"$Command"} scriptblock will get evaluated at run time, which means it will be on the destination machine and $Command will not exist.